# Constraint Layout wrap height quit working

Tags: android

I have had a ConstraintLayout inside a RecyclerView with wrap_content for the height and it has been working perfectly fine. All of a sudden the ConstraingLayout will not wrap_height anymore. I am using androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.1 and androidx.constraintLayout:2.0.1. I have not changed any related code or styling. Any Ideas?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/note"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:background="android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/some_item"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on this. I found the issue. I has an ImageView with wrap_height following the note. Removing wrap_content and giving this ImageView an actual height fixed the issue